# How to mask password entry with on screen keyboard

Tags: security

If I need to enter a password through an on screen keyboard (via touch or mouse) the password can be gleaned by watching the key presses or where the mouse hovers if key press is disabled.

Is there a way to make this process a bit more secure?

Its fine if the user can obscure the screen of the device with his body, but if the screen is projected elsewhere it is an invitation to spread passwords around...

Comment: for this kind of security, except for disabling visual indications (one can still follow the mouse though) is best solved with physical screen filters (like they use in banks etc) to avoid clear view of the screen unless standing right in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is not having a visual indicator of the pressed key.

But that will degrade user experience.

But my first thought is, are you trying to solve the right problem?

Comment: Could you please elucidate on the "solving the right problem" part of your answer? If a user has to use the osk to enter a password I don't really see any other problem to solve...

Comment: your trying to solve a hardware problem with software. Either use a separate keyboard when projecting the screen, or enter your password before connecting to a projector.